# Body email second text with variable

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, email

```
function email(){      
  var a = document.getElementsByName('ctbq');
  var b = document.getElementsByName('ccbq');
  for(i=0;i<a.length;i++){
    var selectedValue = a[i].options[a[i].selectedIndex].value;
    for(i=0;i<b.length;i++){
       var selectedValue2 = b[i].options[b[i].selectedIndex].value;
       cordova.plugins.email.open({
           to:      'teste@gmail.com',
           subject: 'Estoque de Suprimentos',
           body:'Cheios:<br>Toner B431:' + selectedValue '<br>Cilindro B431:'+ selectedValue2,
       });
    }
  }
}
```

Hello, as I'm a beginner I'm having trouble with my code and would like your help, When I digoto my second text with the variable `('<br>Cilindro B431:' + selectedValue2)` in Body my code does not work when I click the submit button. If I leave only the first text with its variable `('Cheios:<br>Toner B431:' + selectedValue)` it works. Can someone help me. I thank you.

Comment: Separate the loops, and build the body text first. Then call the cordova function last, outside of the loops.

Comment: is it a typo or a '+' missing: `body:'Cheios:<br>Toner B431:' + selectedValue '<br>Cilindro B431:'+ selectedValue2`

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to

```
function email(){      
  var a = document.getElementsByName('ctbq');
  var b = document.getElementsByName('ccbq');
  for(i=0;i<a.length;i++){
    var selectedValue = a[i].options[a[i].selectedIndex].value;
    for(i=0;i<b.length;i++){
      var selectedValue2 = b[i].options[b[i].selectedIndex].value;
        cordova.plugins.email.open({
          to:      'teste@gmail.com',
          subject: 'Estoque de Suprimentos',
          body:'Cheios:<br>Toner B431:' + selectedValue + '<br>Cilindro  B431:'+ selectedValue2,
        });
    }
  } 
}
```

I just corrected the typo